# What does "Lay" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I'm reading a book and two guys are arguing,one of the guys says "**Or, you know, I always thought you had a kind of girly face… How many executives do you gotta lay to skip to the top like that, huh?”**

I don't quite understand what "**Lay**" means in this sentence

Comment: To "lay", in that context, means to "have sexual relations with".

Answer (score 1):

As Jack says:

> [**lay**, Etymology 1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lay#English)
> (*transitive, slang*) To have sex with.

This slang word is not something that would be used in formal conversation. More often than not it carries the connotation of sexual relations without emotional attachment; in your context, for example, it is used to refer to the practice of someone "sleeping their way to the top," where they exchange sexual favors for preferential treatment or promotions. (See, as one of many examples, Harvey Weinstein.)